# Raise exception in except block and suppress first error

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm trying to catch an exception and raise a more specific error at a point in my code:

```
try:
  something_crazy()
except SomeReallyVagueError:
  raise ABetterError('message')
```

This works in Python 2, but in Python 3, it shows both exceptions:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
...
SomeReallyVagueError: ...
...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback(most recent call last):
...
ABetterError: message
...
```

Is there some way to get around this, so that `SomeReallyVagueError`'s traceback isn't shown?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Python versions 3.3 and greater, you can use the [`raise <exception> from None`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-raise_stmt) syntax to suppress the traceback of the first exception:

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...     raise ValueError
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
ValueError
>>>
>>>
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...     raise ValueError from None
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
ValueError
>>>
```

Comment: This does require 3.3 or later.

Comment: It worked! I just wrapped it in an `exec` statement because my code needs to run under Python 2 and 3.

Comment: The `raise <exception> from <exception>` was added in 3.0, but the `from None` part of that syntax didn't make it in until 3.3 as part of [PEP 409](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-409-suppressing-exception-context).

Comment: How can this be written to support both Python 2/3?